# Bootstrap Row - right justified

Tags: html, button, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `<h1>` title that that is in a `<div>` row.
I want to fully extend the `<h1>` styling but place a button at the right side of the row.

I cannot figure out how to set the `<span>` value correctly to have the button stay on the right, but also extend the full amount of the row.

The only idea I have is to place the `<h1>` in a `div .span6` and then place the button in another `div span` pulled-right, but that leaves an ugly white space between the `<h1>` title styling and the button.

Also it needs to be fluid in case we have 2 buttons on the right.

[This is just a sample of what I trying to do.](http://jsfiddle.net/pf6FB/)

Answer (score 8):

Your original question was a bit unclear, so I had to guess if something like this was what you were after.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <a href="#" class="btn pull-right">Button 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn pull-right">Button 1</a>
    <h1>My fancy title</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

After you edited the jsfiddle example, I'd say that my solution should work if you're using bootstrap. For some reason your css has `.pull-right{float:none;}` in it that's causing pull-right not to work.

Here's a simple demonstration of your code with only changes being the button being *before* the `h1` and `.pull-right{float:right;}` added to the end of css

http://jsfiddle.net/Arkkimaagi/KFsM6/1/